# "Less/greater than" comparison of N-dimensional and (N-k)-dimensional numpy arrays

Tags: python, arrays, python-3.x, numpy, compare

Given two arrays `a=np.array([[1, 3], [3, 4]])` and `b=np.array([2, 2])`.

The goal: get array `np.array([False, True])` by operation like `a>b`. I.e. compare rows (`True`  if  each pair of elements satisfy the `>` operator  else `False` ) instead of elementwise comparison (i.e. I **don't** want get `np.array([[False, True], [True, True]])`).

And similar for 3-D and (optional) N-dimensional arrays.
E.g.

```
a1 = np.array([[[1, 2, 1], [2, 3, 2]], [[3, 4, 3], [4, 3, 4]]])
b1 = np.array([1, 1, 1])
```

Operation like `a1 > b1` have to return `np.array([[False, True], [True, True]])`.

How to do it?

Comment: Are those always integer arrays?

Comment: I cannot see comparison limitations  based on type of elements. So all comparable (by numpy) types are allowed.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Solution is found: use additionally [`numpy.all`](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.all.html#numpy.all) function.

Usage for my examples:

```
a=np.array([[1, 3], [3, 4]])
b=np.array([2, 2])
numpy.all(a > b, axis=1)
```

Result:

```
array([False,  True], dtype=bool)
```

And

```
a1 = np.array([[[1, 2, 1], [2, 3, 2]], [[3, 4, 3], [4, 3, 4]]])
b1 = np.array([1, 1, 1])
numpy.all(a1 > b1, axis=2)
```

Result:

```
array([[False,  True],
       [ True,  True]], dtype=bool)
```

`numpy.all` also allows pass multiple axes (as tuple of ints), so it can be used for any dimensions.

Also numpy allows to use [`ndarray.all`](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.ndarray.all.html#numpy.ndarray.all) method of numpy arrays. Then examples can be rewritten as `(a>b).all(axis=1)` and `(a1>b1).all(axis=2)` respectively.

Comment: `(A>B).all(axis=-1)` would be a generic way to put it for any Ndarray as long as the reduction is along the last axis.